# How to change \parskip in bibliography section?

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, natbib, parskip

I want to change a vertical interval between `\bibitem`-s in my bibliography section. Now it is the same as in the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
[...]
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.3cm}
[...]
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{my-bib-file}
\end{document}
```

I would like to set it to `0.1cm`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Preliminary remark: If you want to change the spacing between paragraphs, use the [parskip](ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/parskip.html) package or a [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/koma-script.html)-classs - simply changing the `\parskip` length may have adverse affects.

As the bibliography is a (special) list environment, it shouldn't be affected by `\parskip` - maybe its vertical spacing is accidentally about 0.3cm.

Having said all that, the following works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{a01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}

@misc{b02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

% Changing vertical spacing in the bibliography
% Alternative A
% \usepackage{etoolbox}
% \patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\sloppy}{\itemsep 0.1cm \parsep 0pt \sloppy}{}{}
% Alternative B
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.1cm}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

If it doesn't work for you, also provide a minimal example.

EDIT: Code example changed in order to work for `natbib`.

EDIT2: Why not simply change the `\bibsep` length?

Comment: Sorry, no effect :(

Comment: @Vincenzo: I edited my answer to include a minimal example to show that it works for me.

Comment: I also use `natbib`. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: @Vincenzo: Not only maybe. Please provide a complete example next time.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably you need:
https://texfaq.org/FAQ-compactbib

The first way is by using package [natbib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/natbib.html) and changing the length of `\bibsep`,
and the second way is by redefinition of `\thebibliography`.